# What's the simplest SQL to show the overlap between 3 lists?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have 3 lists of strings `a`, `b`, and `c`.

I want to set up some joins so that it will be clear which values are in `a` only, which are in `b` only, which are in `a` and `c` only, etc., like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |  c  |
+-----+-----+-----+
| xyz | xyz |     |
|     | abc | abc |
| 123 | 123 | 123 |
|     |     | fna |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I was thinking i can do something like:

```
select a.a, b.b, c.c from
(a
left join
b
on
a.a=b.b)
left join
c
on
a.a=c.c

union

select a.a, b.b, c.c from
(b
left join
a
on
a.a=b.b)
left join
c
on
b.b=c.c

union

select a.a, b.b, c.c from
(c
left join
a
on
a.a=c.c)
left join
b
on
b.b=c.c
```

But in addition to being very long, this is an expensive query because it's joining the same 3 lists 3 times.  Is there a more efficient way to rewrite this query and get the desired results shown in the example table above?

Comment: if by lists you mean datasets/tables `FROM A FULL OUTER JOIN B on A.A = B.B FULL OUTER JOIN C on C.C=B.B or A.A=C.C`  take note of the OR on the last join

Comment: @xQbert, Access 2010 doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Nor can you use `UNION ALL` in a subquery.  MS Access just isn't a good tool for this.